# MEF update exported part metadata (the metadata view is invalid because property has a property set method)

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, ioc-container

I have an application and I'm using MEF to compose it. I want to know if it is possible to update the Metadata information of the parts after they were imported.

The reason to do this is the following: I display the imported parts' name and an typeof(int) property in a ListBox, and they are not loaded until the corresponding ListBoxItem is selected (pretty standard). Now I want to update the Metadata info of one part when some event raises, so the displayed info in the ListBox is somethind like "[Part name] ([new number])".

I'm importing the metadata as an Interface that defines it's info, but when I set the int property to be editable (with a set accesor) I receive the following execption at composition time:

```
"The  MetadataView 'myMetadataInterface' is invalid 
 because property 'myInt' has a property set method."
```

Is there ANY way to achieve this? Or is the metadata ALWAYS read only once the part is created?

I know this question looks weird, but it doesn't make it any less difficult and therefore interesting ;-)

---

EDIT (based on Lee's answer, in order to keep people to the core of the question)

I just want to know if it is possible to update a Metadata property after the part is composed, but before it is actually loaded (HasValue == false). Don't worry about filtering or finding the part.

I added a property to the export inteface, which is meant only to be represented in the UI and to be updated, this property has no other function and the parts are not filtered by it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Metadata filtering and DefaultValueAttribute**
>
> When you specifiy a metadata view, an implicit filtering will occur to
>   match only those exports which contain the metadata properties defined
>   in the view. You can specify on the metadata view that a property is
>   not required, by using the
>   System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute. Below you can see where
>   we have specified a default value of false on IsSecure. This means if
>   a part exports IMessageSender, but does not supply IsSecure metadata,
>   then it will still be matched.

[citation](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata)

**Short Version** (EDITED in after question edit).

You shouldn't ever need to update metadata at runtime. If you have some data that should be updated and belongs to a mef part, you need to choose to either have it be updated by recompiling, or store that data in a flexible storage outside of the dll. There's no way to store the change you made in the dll without recompiling, so this is a flawed design.

**Previous post.**

Altering values on the **view** would by lying about the components loaded. Sure the metadata is just an interface to an object that returns initialized values; sure you can technically update those values, but that's not the purpose of metadata.

You wouldn't be changing the `Name` field of an instance of `Type`. Why not? Because it's metadata. Updating metadata at runtime would imply that the nature of the instance of real data is somehow modified.

This line of code, if possible, wouldn't introduce the Triple type.

```
typeof(Double).Name = "Triple";
var IGotATriple = new Triple();
```

If you want to alter values, you need to just make another object with that information and bind to that. Metadata is compiled in. If you change it after a part is loaded, it doesn't change anything in the part's source, so you'd be lying. (unless you're going to have access to the source-code and you change it there and recompile).

Let's look at an example:

```
[Export(typeof(IPart))]
[ExportMetadata("Part Name","Gearbox")]
[ExportMetadata("Part Number","123")]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class GearBoxPart : Part { public double GearRatio ... }
```

Now, let's assume that you had a UI that showed available parts and their numbers. Now, the manufacturer changes the part number for whatever reason and you want to update it. If this is possible, you might want to consider storing part number in a manifest or database instead. Alternatively you'd have to recompile every time a part number changes.

Recompile is possible. You have a controller UI that does the above, but instead of updating the metadata, you submit a request to rebuild the part's codefile. The request would be handled by parsing the codefile, replacing the part number, then sending off for a batch recompile and redistribute the new dll. That's a lot of work for nothing IMO.

So, you setup a database. Then you change the object metadata to this.

```
[ExportMetadata("OurCompanyNamePartNumber","123")]
```

Then you have a database/manifest/xml that maps your unique permanent static part number that your company devises to the current part number. Modifications in your control UI update the database/manifest/xml.

```
<PartMap>
    <PartMapEntry OurCompanyNamePartNumber="123" ManufacturerPartNumber="456"/>
    ...
</PartMap>
```

Then the end-user UI does lookups for the part by manufacturer part number, and the mef code looks in the PartMap to get the mef part number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lee. I don't understand what you mean by "so you'd be lying", care to explain?
Your last comment is what I want to achieve: update data on demand that is associated with a mef part metadata... would you give a quick example or guidelines? Thanks again.

Comment: Your metadata view describes the query for the types you'll retrieve, changing that at run time is essentially "lying" about what you retrieved. If it's data about the class that needs to update, then you should have another method of storing that data. mef metadata isn't a database.

Comment: Thank you Lee for updating your answer, but I think you are asuming some things that do not apply to my case. I have in the metadata an int property I only use to update, the "filter" is made with other properties. This int property is only to update the display without the need to load the whole part.
I want to know just if it is possible to update one property without reloading all parts, don't worry about the "lying".
I appreciate all the effort you put in your answer, just for that I'm voting it up. Regards.

Comment: @Hannish Ok, so I looked at your edit in your question, and I think you're doing it wrong. You should never have to update a property within metadata at runtime. If this is what you're trying to do, then don't. Make another object and copy the metadata property into that, then update that at runtime. Even if you did that, you have no place to save the change unless you recompile the mef part dll. **It's not a matter of whether metadata can be updated at runtime, but whether it should.** In this case, if you want data to update without a recompile, it shouldn't be metadata.

Comment: Thank you Lee, I think the idea of copying the metadata into another object and then updating that object might do the trick. I'm not so sure if the metadata should not be updated, because I'm putting a property in the metadata just for the updating purpose... if I was not going to update it, that property would not exist. I just wanted to avoid loading a big object just to display a number on screen.